# PhantomJS does not work with proxy

Tags: proxy, phantomjs

I can make SoapUI work with this proxy on port 8080 but not PhantomJS.

I typed in command line

```
nslookup proxy
```

to get the proxy IP, it gave me 2 IPs

```
Serveur:  myserverurl
Address:  myserverip

Nom:      myproxyurl
Address:  myproxyip
Aliases:  myproxyalias
```

I tried both IPs with this PhantomJS command

```
phantomjs.exe --proxy=ip:8080 hello.js
```

None works, why?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You might need to select the correct [proxy type (http/socks5/none)](http://phantomjs.org/api/command-line.html):

```
phantomjs --proxy=ip:8080 --proxy-type=http hello.js
```

or

```
phantomjs --proxy=ip:8080 --proxy-type=socks5 hello.js
```

You might also try to combine those:

```
phantomjs --proxy=http://ip:8080 hello.js
```

or

```
phantomjs --proxy=socks5://ip:8080 hello.js
```